# Uncertainty in L,a,b space of compressed JPEG images

Tags: image, image-processing, colors, jpeg, uncertainty

My team wish to calculate the contrast between two photographs taken in a wet environment.

We will calculate contrast using the formula

Contrast = SQRT((ΔL)^2 + (Δa)^2 + (Δb)^2)

where ΔL is the difference in luminosity, Δa is the difference in (redness-greeness) and Δb is (yellowness-blueness), which are the dimensions of Lab space.

Our (so far successful) approach has been to convert each pixel from RGB to Lab space, and taking the mean values of the relevant sections of the image as our A and B variables.

However the environment limits us to using a (waterproof) GoPro camera which compresses images to JPEG format, rather than saving as TIFF, so we are not using a true-colour image.

We now need to quantify the uncertainty in the contrast - for which we need to know the uncertainty in A and B and by extension the uncertainties (or mean/typical uncertainty) in each a and b value for each RGB pixel. We can calculate this only if we know the typical/maximum uncertainty produced when converting from true-colour to JPEG.

**Therefore we need to know the maximum possible difference in each of the RGB channels when saving in JPEG format.**

EG. if true colour RGB pixel (5, 7, 9) became (2, 9, 13) after compression the uncertainty in each channel would be (+/- 3, +/- 2, +/- 4).

We believe that the camera compresses colour in the aspect ratio 4:2:0 - is there a way to test this?

However our main question is; is there any way of knowing the maximum possible error in each channel, or calculating the uncertainty from the compressed RGB result?

*Note: We know it is impossible to convert back from JPEG to TIFF as JPEG compression is lossy. We merely need to quantify the extent of this loss on colour.*

Comment: What library are you working with? Native WIC / WPF stuff or something bespoke?

Comment: We're currently using Python's PIL library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, it is **not** possible to absolutely quantify the maximum possible difference in digital counts in a JPEG image.

You highlight one of these points well already. When image data is encoded using the JPEG standard, it is first converted to the YCbCr color space.

Once in this color space, the chroma channels (Cb and Cr) are downsampled, because the human visual system is less sensitive to artifacts in chroma information than it is lightness information.

The error introduced here is content-dependent; an area of very rapidly varying chroma and hue will have considerably more content loss than an area of constant hue/chroma.
Even knowing the 4:2:0 compression, which describes the amount and geometry of downsampling (more information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling#Sampling_systems_and_ratios)), the content still dictates the error introduced at this step.

Another problem is the quantization performed in JPEG compression.

The resulting information is encoded using a Discrete Cosine Transform. In the transformed space, the results are again quantized depending on the desired quality. This quantization is set at the time of file generation, which is performed in-camera. Again, even if you knew the exact DCT quantization being performed by the camera, the actual effect on RGB digital counts is ultimately content-dependent.

Yet another difficulty is noise created by DCT block artifacts, which (again) is content dependent.

These scene dependencies make the algorithm very good for visual image compression, but very difficult to characterize absolutely.

However, there is some light at the end of the tunnel. JPEG compression will cause significantly more error in areas of rapidly changing image content. Areas of constant color and texture will have significantly less compression error and artifacts. Depending on your application you may be able to leverage this to your benefit.